# How to control genfromtxt to read rows specified?

Tags: numpy, scipy, genfromtxt

`genfromtxt` can skip header and footer lines and speicfy which columns to use. 
But how can I control how many lines to read?

Sometimes a txt file might contain several blocks with different shape.
For example,

```
a=StringIO('''
1,2,3
1,2,3
2,3
2,3
''')
genfromtxt(a,delimiter=',',skip_header=1)
```

This will raise an error,

```
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #4 (got 2 columns instead of 3)
    Line #5 (got 2 columns instead of 3)
```

Of couse, I can do it like this:

```
a=StringIO('''
1,2,3
1,2,3
2,3
2,3
''')
genfromtxt(a,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,skip_footer=2)
```

It's ugly as I have to calculate the number of rows under the block.

However I wish something like

```
genfromtxt(a,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,nrows=2)
```

that would be more clear.

Anyone have a good idea about that? Or use other function?

---

### Update 2015 Oct

This question has been **solved** in new version of `Numpy`.

`genfromtxt` now have a new keywords named `max_rows` which allow one to control the number of lines to read, cf [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5496).

Comment: `fromfile` offer a keyword `count` can control Number of items to read. However `fromfile` is less flexible than `genfromtxt` or `loadtxt` when reading txt file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `invalid_raise = False` to skip reading the lines that are missing some data.
E.g.

```
b = np.genfromtxt(a, delimiter=',', invalid_raise=False)
```

This will give you a warning, but will not raise an exception.

Comment: If you want to filter that warning, you can add this,

    `import warnings`
    `warnings.simplefilter("ignore",UserWarning)`